# deploying apk to google play with visibility

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

How can I deploy apk to google play that it couldn't be found by search, but still avalaible by direct link. I tryed to create open alpha test, but Application can still be found by search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed Beta/Alpha is what you are looking for.
You will allow users by emails only and these users are the only users who can find your app by search.

> **Closed beta**: Consider closed beta testing if you want to run a test
>   with a smaller group (like within your company or team) or when you
>   know the exact users you want to test your app. If you're testing an
>   existing app that you've published before, only users in your test
>   group will receive an update for your alpha/beta version.
>
> **Open beta**: Consider open beta testing if you want to run a test with a
>   large group and surface your app's beta version on the Play Store. If
>   you run an open beta test, anyone can join your beta program and
>   submit private feedback to you. Make sure your app is ready for
>   visibility on the Play Store before choosing this option.
>
> Keep in mind, the open and closed beta version of your app won't have
>   public ratings.

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah, i've read about it, But i don't know emails of testers, I want to publish it and share url with some people without adding their emails.

Comment: I don't think that such option is available, I think you can only do so by open beta and the app will be public available by search and any one can join, and it is something logically, if you don't know the testers's emails how you will send them the link!

Comment: Well it supposed to be that i share link with their head, and he will share it among them.

Comment: then ask him to send you their emails

Comment: No, It's good what you said, I read about it, I thought it might be other way to grant what I need. But if there is no way, ok, so let it be open beta! Thank you